# Using strings in existing text - ObjC

Tags: objective-c, string, popup

Ok, so what I'm trying to accomplish is a little pop-up box that says "Hello, John!"

"John" would be a value of a string.

I'm more of a C# programmer so something like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome, " + name + "!";
```

Here's the code I have now.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *name = [prefs stringForKey:@"name"];
UIAlertView *welcome = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(@"Welcome back, " + "%@", name)message:@"Welcome back :)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];

[welcome show];
}
```

Comment: Read the `NSString` documentation and look into string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use [NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format,, ...]

The line would look like this:

```
UIAlertView *welcome = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:([NSString stringWithFormat: @"Welcome back, %@", name]) message:@"Welcome back :)" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
```

Comment: I get the error - Thread 1: breakpoint 1:1 when running the code.

Comment: It is not an error.
Remove the breakpoint or hit ctrl+command+Y to continue. Read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I'm new to all of this.